# How to make html text scroll when div size exceeded?

Tags: html, marquee

I have an html page that is displayed on a television screen sort of like digital signage. Because of this, everything that is on the page has to be displayed without any user input. I have some records stored in a mySQL database that are displayed in a list format and what I would like to do is when the list gets to big to be displayed, it scrolls up (maybe one line at a time) similar to how a scrolling marquee works.

My ideas on how to do this are fragmented at best, I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

btw, I know using the marquee tag is "evil" to a lot of developers, however in this case because there is no user input, I don't see any other way.

Edit: What I had in mind was to somehow get the div height and then use an if statement to trigger a marquee when the height exceeds a predetermined size.

Edit: Here is what I've got so far, using JavaScript to figure out the div height...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function divHeight()
{
  var height = document.getElementById("list").offsetHeight;

  if (height > 500)
  {
  activate marquee effect.
  return;
  }
  else
  {
  don't activate marquee effect.
  return;
  }

}
</script>
```

Then...

```
<body onLoad="divHeight()">
<div id="list">
my list goes here
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: do you try it via css... ? As overflow:auto ...?

Comment: I did, but that just gives a scroll bar if the text overflows the div. Normally that would be fine, but there is no user interaction on this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a nice way to do this with very little coding. It uses `JavaScript` to alter the `div` contents if the size is exceeded. I've got the text that I want to scroll inside `div id="scroll"` and that `div` is populated with my data from the `mySQL` database using `php`. Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var div = document.getElementById("scroll");
var height = div.offsetHeight;
var content = div.innerHTML;

if (height > 500)
{
div.innerHTML = "<marquee direction=\"up\" scrollamount=\"2\" height=\"500px\" onfinish=\"redirect()\" loop=\"1\">" + content + "</marquee>";
}

function redirect()
{
refresh=window.setTimeout(function(){location.href=""},0);
}
</script>
```

Since this application is for digital signage, I have it redirect once the full `marquee` content has been displayed, that's why I have `onfinish="redirect"` and then a function to redirect.

Hopefully this will help someone out, I know I spent a lot of time scratching my head over it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this page

http://www.webdesignbooth.com/create-a-vertical-scrolling-news-ticker-with-jquery-and-jcarousel-lite/

They did it using jcarousel lite. I would have written an example by myself but I found this good example first saving me from do it ;)

Comment: That's pretty cool, I like the looks of that. It doesn't really achieve what I was after though, because it always scrolls. 
 With my project there might only be a few lines of data which would fit without needing to scroll, whereas other times there will be too much data to fit and will therefore need to scroll.

Comment: I'm sure you could get it done with a bit of code to customize jcarousel behavior

Comment: I guess it's time for me to dip my toes into jQuery!